# Need an alarm clock that uses Windows 7 taskbar right click features

Tags: windows-7

I am looking for an alarm clock program that will allow you to right-click the windows 7 taskbar and select something like "alert me in 15 minutes". Also I would like it to have setting that allow you to pick the sound and be able to schedule a daily alarm. Also I want it to look nice. If anyone knows of one I would appreciate a link. I am seriously considering learning how to make it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try [TimeLeft](http://download.cnet.com/TimeLeft/3000-2350_4-10034817.html), a free download from CNET.